# How can I create a branch and new remote tracking branch at once?

Tags: git

I normally create a new branch via `git checkout -b ...` and the first time I push to it I'm prompted to use the --set-upstream argument to create a new remote tracking branch.  Can I do this in one command when I create the branch?   I have tried the following (per [instructions here](https://coderwall.com/p/tlednq/create-a-new-branch-and-track-a-remote-branch)):

```
   % git checkout -b mybranch20200423 --track origin/mybranch20200423                          
fatal: 'origin/mybranch20200423' is not a commit and a branch 'mybranch20200423' cannot be created from it

   % git checkout -b mybranch20200423 origin/mybranch20200423        
fatal: 'origin/mybranch20200423' is not a commit and a branch 'mybranch20200423' cannot be created from it
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Why does git think that 'origin/mybranch20200423' is supposed to be a commit?

Comment: does `origin/mybranch20200423` exist beforehand and have you fetched it before creating the new branch?

Comment: @mnestorov no it doesn't - I'm trying to create it at the same time as I create my local branch.

Comment: I bet that a git guru can prove me wrong, but I fear that you can't create a local and a remote branch at the same time. Creating remote branches isn't as simple as just naming the branch `origin/xxx`. What I can think of as a possible solution for you is to have a `git alias` that will create a local branch, push it, and then track, making it a one command. Do you think that would be acceptable for you?

Comment: git is giving you that error, because it doesn't see that branch. If that branch existed beforehand, you could `git fetch` it, but since it doesn't exist, there is nothing to track from the start.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can do something like that.  I may wait until I get a little more familiar with git though before "hiding" the normal syntax and flows with aliases though.

Comment: I guess it just seemed odd that every time I create a new branch and try to push to it, I need to run the additional "set upstream" command.  It seemed like something that could/should be done automatically at the time of branch creation.

Comment: When pushing your local branch to your remote, you can pass the `-u` parameter, so that it starts tracking that branch automatically. So that can save you one command at least.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have all the details of the `git branch` command, but it looks like the `--track` and `--set-upstream` options only expect *existing* branch names :

```
$ git branch --set-upstream origin/foo/bar
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/foo/bar' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

Providing a remote branch name can be done when pushing using `git push -u <branchname>`.

---

To handle the "push a new branch" case, I use the following command :

```
git push origin -u $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` will give the name of the current active branch,
- `$(...)` injects it as an argument to the outer command,
- `git push -u <branchname>` will push current commit to remote branch `<branchname>` and add `origin/branchname` as the tracked upstream branch.

---

I added an alias for it :

```
git config --global config.pushnew '! git push origin -u $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

so that typing :

```
git pushnew
```

in a terminal from a new branch pushes my new branch without needing to repeat the branch name.

Comment: You can in fact just use `git push -u origin HEAD`: Git converts `HEAD` from symbolic reference to branch name locally, then does the push.

Comment: @torek : nice, didn't know about that one. I have one extra use case : we actually have several remotes, so `git pushnew upstream1` and `git pushnew upstream2` also work.

Answer (score 1):

See [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61391906/1256452).

As an alternative, consider creating the branch on the remote first:

```
git fetch origin            # update origin/master if/as needed
git push origin origin/master:newbranch
```

The first step, which you only need if your remote-tracking branches may be out of date (but it's safe to use any time), has your Git call up their Git, get any new commits from them, save them in your clone, and update all your `origin/*` names.  (I like to use `--prune` here too, but I do that with `git config fetch.prune true` so that Git just does it automatically.)

The `git push` step has your Git call up the Git over at `origin` and asks them to create-or-update their branch-name `newbranch` based on your `origin/master`, which—if you have updated recently enough—is in sync now with their `master`.  That is, you're asking them to create *their* branch `newbranch` based on (your copy of) their `master`, since `newbranch` does not yet exist in their repository.

Assuming they obey this polite "create or update" request, `newbranch` now exists on `origin`.  Now that `newbranch` *does* exist on `origin`, your own Git creates `origin/newbranch`.

Now you can simply run:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

which will discover that, gosh, you don't have a branch named `newbranch`, but you do have `origin/newbranch`, so it should *create* `newbranch` from `origin/newbranch`.  If your Git predates Git 2.23, you might want to use `git checkout --track origin/newbranch` to avoid an ambiguity, and if it's 2.23 or later, you might want to use `git switch newbranch`, but in general this mostly works.

I don't do any of the above: I just create the branch locally myself as appropriate.  Then, on the first `git push`, I use the shorthand `git push -u origin HEAD` (after double checking, with `git status`, that I'm on the right branch and everything is ready).